# Can I use realize with "just" in the present tense?

Tags: adverbs, present-tense

Example:

> I just realize why you hate me

Comment: I've just realized why you hate me.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but not in that way.

If you wanted to say that you've come to know only a brief moment ago that the person you're talking to hates you, then the simplest way to change your original sentence to be correct is like this:

> I've just realized you hate me.

However, you can use the phrase "just realize," as illustrated by the reply from the other person:

> Did you *just* realize that I hate you?

Alternate version of the same question in past tense:

> Have you *just* realized that I hate you?

I don't think you can use "just realize" outside of a question, though. Someone correct me if I am wrong on this.

It should be noted that despite the fact that the tenses are different, the meanings are virtually identical. The reason is the use of the word "just," which is used as an adverb to mean that it happened very recently. We understand that the realization happened only a second ago in both sentences even though the tenses are different.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is technically correct.  However, it's most likely never going to be used that way.  Realize is the present tense of the verb.  For that particular sentence, you would need to use the past tense ("I just **realized** why you hate me") or present progressive with a revision ("I **am realizing** why you hate me").

Comment: The sentence isn't so much *ungrammatical* as *highly unlikely*; reinterpreting "just" the way it's used in "I just don't like that" would work, but means something very unusual.

Comment: edited @NathanTuggy

Comment: Souldn't the tense be consistent? Like ( I realized why you hated me/was hating me)

Comment: Well, in your case, does the person still hate you? If so, there's no problem in tense consistency, the hatred is an ongoing state (present), the realization just occurred (past).